# In which tense is more common to use in this context?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, grammaticality-in-context, past-continuous

I have a two tenses / ways to express my situation but I'm not sure what's more natural.

I rushed / was rushing to the class,  and when I arrived I found that nobody is there.

> "I **rushed** to the class for nothing…  nobody is here". (Past simple tense)
>
> "I **was rushing** to the class for nothing…  nobody is here". (Past continous)

Comment: Are you actually saying this to yourself at the moment you found out there is nobody in the class (like a character in a book who is thinking to themselves)? Or are you telling this to a friend later in the day?

Answer (score 1):

"I **rushed** to the class, and when I arrived I found that nobody **was** there." sounds more natural. I would only use "was rushing" if something happened while you were rushing.